# Do regression analysis for all the variable X and response G, for all data frames found under one data frame in R

Tags: r, regression, analysis, bulk

I have a data frame (df) which looks like this:

```
group.no Amount Response
1          5       10
1         10       25
1          2       20
2         12       20
2          4        8
2          3        5
```

and I have split the data.frame into several data.frames based on their group number with

```
  out <- split( df , f = df$group.no )
```

Now what I want is to do a regression analysis with lm between the amount ~ response for all the new data.frames in the "out" 
Please consider this is an example and I have 500 splitted data.frames in "out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.  Specify `pool = FALSE` as an `lmList` argument if you don't want to pool the standard errors.

```
# 1
library(nlme)
lmList(Response ~ Amount | group.no, DF)
```

An alternative is:

```
# 2
lm(Response ~ grp / (Amount + 1) - 1, transform(DF, grp = factor(group.no)))
```

or this which carries out completely separate regressions:

```
# 3
by(DF, DF$group.no, function(DF) lm(Response ~ Amount, DF))
```

This last line can also be written:

```
# 3a
by(DF, DF$group.no, lm, formula = Response ~ Amount)
```

### R squared

We can compute R squared by group using any of these:

```
summary(lmList(Response ~ Amount | group.no, DF))$r.squared

c(by(DF, DF$group.no, function(x) summary(lm(Response ~ Amount, x))$r.squared))

reg.list <- by(DF, DF$group.no, lm, formula = Response ~ Amount)
sapply(reg.list, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)

c(by(DF, DF$group.no, with, cor(Response, Amount)^2))

library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(group.no) %>%
  do(summarize(., r.squared = summary(lm(Response ~ Amount, .))$r.squared)) %>%
  ungroup
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "group.no Amount Response
1          5       10
1         10       25
1          2       20
2         12       20
2          4        8
2          3        5"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. wit ```DF <- by(df, df$group.no, lm, formula = Response ~ Amount.)``
Do you know how can I list only the R2?

Comment: Have moved comments to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the regression you could use either `magrittr` or `dplyr` to first split and then create a list of linear regressions:

```
library(magrittr) #alternative library(dplyr)
df %>% split(.$group.no) %>% lapply(function(x) lm(Amount ~ Response, data = x))
```

If you wish to avoid the `dplyr` syntax a single `lapply` call can be used as

```
lapply(split(df, df$group.no), function(x) lm(Amount ~ Response, data = x))
```

Comment: Thanks second one worked awesome, also I found that I could do this:

```lmList(Amount ~ Response, | group.no, df) ```

without splitting them in different data.frames. Do u know how can I print only the R2 of these regression models?

Comment: Glad i could help. It is definitely possible using `lmList` from the `lme4` or `nlme` package as well. Hopefuly either will be sufficient to your problem. Remember to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) useful answers and mark an answer as the answer to the question to incentivize future answers.

Answer (score 0):

`out` is a list of dataframes so you can use `lapply()` to estimate your regression for each dataframe.

```
mods <- lapply(out, lm, formula=y~x)
```

And then `mods` will be a list of the models.